# WPF, What tool and layout is right for my application?

Tags: .net, wpf

My WPF application involves drawing shapes, and then spreading the shapes (basically spreading the shapes like blocks to create objects) on the screen. Application is in wpf. All this is in 2d (but it'll be good to have a way to make it 3d in future). Sections will have to be selectable and mathematical and geographical calculations will also be performed on them.

I have done some search on using 2d libraries and canvas layout. What i am looking for is the equivalent of a drawing screen in WPF, or something to create it, and other stuff which i need to study in order to get the job done. So what are the right tools for the job?

Comment: You already found `Canvas`. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Thriple from Josh Smith](http://thriple.codeplex.com/), like an API for 3D rendering in WPF environment. If you you are going to jump to 3D soon or later, consider using this kind of API, or may be others this is just an example, just now, by avoiding rendering in deep buffer.

This kind of libraries end up into [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx), by the way. 
So the choice is up to you:

or use some already build framework with its limitations, bugs and limited support

or make your own 3D Api, but you need to dig into 3D rendering, if you never did something before, can take quite a lot time to become familiar with and develop something serious.

But based on on your own professional interests, can bring to you huge satisfaction too.

Regards.